# String Array returning [[object Object]] at restTemplate

Tags: java, api, object, resttemplate

I'm trying to use one api that in the response body we have this structure:

```
{"flag": false,
"codes":[
    "a3f2b9ddf8886b04993632"]}
```

At Postman, and executing a curl, the response is exactly this one.

But when I use restTemplate.exchange(...) to return the response body,it's always returning for **codes**: [[object Object]]

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(URL...); //cannot show partner's url here

header.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
header.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

ResponseEntity<String> resourceHttpEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
    builder.toUriString(),
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new HttpEntity<>(header), String.class); //header also has an authorization bearer token that is in another class

System.out.println(resourceHttpEntity.getBody());
```

Response body from this:

```
{"flag":false,"codes":["[object Object]"]}
```

I saw some examples that this occurs, but in Javascript, and we use JSON.stringfy to solve it.

But at Java we don't have this option. I don't know if is a miss-configuration or something.

Even I try to get this response body with the class model using String[], ArrayList for this property. Tried to convert in String.class, JSonNode.class, and it's returning this way.

I tried to use objectMapper to convert, and even test with HTTPURLConnection to confirm and it's happening the same thing. I have the same result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print the content of a generic object in Json format you can print it as follow:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
System.out.println(ow.writeValueAsString(object)); 
// Or better log.info(ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

If you don't need to format your output you can call directly [`writeValueAsString`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)) on the `objectMapper`:

> Method that can be used to serialize any Java value as a String

```
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object));
```

---

Updated answer after the update on the question.

It seems that the remote service that you are invoking is returning exactly the body that you showed in the updated answer.
Your code is treating the body as a simple string, so there is no manipulation on the client-side (your code). It means that is possible that for particular values the server-side (the web service that you are invoking) is performing some strange operation (probably a bean to json conversion) that will generate this output.

You have many ways to check it:

- make the same call using postman
- make the same call using curl
- add a sniffer between your client and the server and use it to log the passing data

For the first two alternatives you have to be sure to use exactly the same data used by the java code. And execute them from the same machine (may be that a proxy can change the behaviour of the call).

Comment: Tried to do that, still receiving [ "[object Object]" ]

Comment: @AnniCarol what it means that you receive [ "[object Object]" ]  ? Can you update your question posting the code where you see that [ "[object Object]" ]  ?

Comment: @AnniCarol I updated the answer. It seems that your code is correct and the problem is on the web service side

Comment: Thank you @Davide!  I already tried with postman, curl and it's working. I gonna try to talk to partner's support team and see if we have a solution for that and any news I'll add here.

Answer (score 0):

We discover that the RestTemplate @Bean that we already have in code, was causing this issue. So I just instantiate a new RestTemplate from scratch, and the issue was resolved.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Create Java class with below attributes and use as response entity type.

```
Public class Response{
boolean flag;
List<String> codes;
}

ResponseEntity<Response> resourceHttpEntity = 
restTemplate.exchange(
builder.toUriString(),
HttpMethod.GET,
new HttpEntity<>(header), Response.class);
```